# How to extract digest algorithm from signed dll using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, digital-signature, digest

I have a dll file which is digitally signed. I need to write a PowerShell command which could get me the Digest Algorithm that is used for the Digital Signature.

Digest Algorithm info I need:

[image: DigestAlgorithm Info what I need to extract]

I tried with `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` but this didn't get me the Digest Algorithm info.

After running the following command I get the below result.

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Program Files\Application Verifier\vrfauto.dll" | Format-List
```

Results of above:
[image: Result of execution]

Comment: Related: [How to extract all the list of digest algorithm from signed dll using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57849240/3439404)

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for is

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature | %{
    $_.SignerCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName
}
```

Lets go over how we got to there. First i find a file that has a Digital Signature. I will use **PowerShell-6.1.2-win-x64.msi** for this example.

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\test\PowerShell-6.1.2-win-x64.msi | get-member
```

We see there is a object for the **SignerCertificate**

```
SignerCertificate      Property   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 SignerCertificate {get;}
```

So lets see what that holds

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\test\PowerShell-6.1.2-win-x64.msi | %{
    $_.SignerCertificate | get-member
}
```

Now we see there is a **SignatureAlgorithm** property

```
SignatureAlgorithm              Property       System.Security.Cryptography.Oid SignatureAlgorithm {get;}
```

Now we dig one more deep

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\test\PowerShell-6.1.2-win-x64.msi | %{
    $_.SignerCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm | get-member
}
```

We get :

```
FriendlyName Property   string FriendlyName {get;set;}
Value        Property   string Value {get;set;}
```

We can see there both strings so we test out which is better for us...turns out its friendly name :

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\test\PowerShell-6.1.2-win-x64.msi | %{
    $_.SignerCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName
}
```

Returns

```
sha256RSA
```

Comment: `$result.TimeStamperCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName` gives me digest algorithm that is shown in Windows Explorer.